# Detect Data in UITextView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, touchesbegan, datadetectortypes

I have a `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell` subclass. It has `editable` and `userInteractionEnabled` both set to `NO`. This allows the `UITextView` to detect data such as links and phone numbers. The data is detected correctly, but because userInteraction is disabled, it cannot respond to taps on that data. If I set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`, it works fine, but then the `UITableViewCell` cannot be selected since the UITextView swallows the touch.

**I want to follow the link if the user taps on it, but I want `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to be called if the tap is on basic text.**

I think the right approach is to subclass `UITextView` and pass touches to the cell, but I can't seem to find a way to detect whether or not the tap was on a link.

This is a similar question, but the answer will just pass all touches to the cell. I want to only pass the touches if they are NOT on a piece of detected data.
[issue enabling dataDetectorTypes on a UITextView in a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347727/issue-enabling-datadetectortypes-on-a-uitextview-in-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Can you try txtView.selectable = NO; or userInteration set yes and use UITapGestureRecognizer???

Comment: Don't you think if the `UITextView` is editable *and* links selectable, the user might find it a bit hard to **edit** the links ?

Comment: One possible (and complex) solution would be to use what I do in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827035/tap-gesture-on-part-of-uilabel) question, by disabling link detection, and using tappable `UIView`s instead. (again, complicated). Maybe someone else has a better solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [issue enabling dataDetectorTypes on a UITextView in a UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347727/issue-enabling-datadetectortypes-on-a-uitextview-in-a-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 1. Using `hitTest(_:with:)`

`UIView` has a method called [`hitTest(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest) that has the following definition:

```
func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
```

> Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy (including itself) that contains a specified point.

`UITextView` being a subclass of `UIView`, you can implement this method in any subclass of `UITextView` you may want to create.

---

The following Swift 3 example shows a `UITableViewController` that contains a single static `UITableViewCell`. The `UITableViewCell` embeds a `UITextView`. Any tap on a link inside the `UITextView` will launch Safari app; any tap on basic text inside the `UITextView` will trigger a push segue to the following `UIViewController`.

*LinkTextView.swift*

```
import UIKit

class LinkTextView: UITextView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        isScrollEnabled = false
        isEditable = false
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        isSelectable = true
        dataDetectorTypes = .link
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // Get the character index from the tap location
        let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: point, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        // if we detect a link, handle the tap by returning self...
        if let _ = textStorage.attribute(NSLinkAttributeName, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) {
            return self
        }

        // ... otherwise return nil ; the tap will go on to the next receiver
        return nil
    }

}
```

*TextViewCell.swift*

```
import UIKit

class TextViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: LinkTextView!

}
```

*TableViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cell: TextViewCell!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add text to cell's textView

        let text = "http://www.google.com Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, http://www.yahoo.com sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        cell.textView.text = text
    }

}
```

[image]

---

### 2. Using `point(inside:with:)`

As an alternative to override `hitTest(_:with:)`, you can use [`point(inside:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622533-point). `point(inside:with:)` has the following declaration:

```
func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
```

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the receiver contains the specified point.

---

The following code shows how to implement `point(inside:with:)` instead of `hitTest(_:with:)` in your `UITextView` subclass:

*LinkTextView.swift*

```
import UIKit

class LinkTextView: UITextView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        isScrollEnabled = false
        isEditable = false
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        isSelectable = true
        dataDetectorTypes = .link
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        // Get the character index from the tap location
        let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: point, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        // if we detect a link, handle the tap by returning true...
        if let _ = textStorage.attribute(NSLinkAttributeName, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) {
            return true
        }

        // ... otherwise return false ; the tap will go on to the next receiver
        return false
    }

}
```

---

The complete project is available on this GitHub repo: [LinkTextViewCell](https://github.com/imanoupetit/LinkTextViewCell).

You can learn more about managing a `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell` by reading [Swifty Approach to Handling UITextViews With Links in Cells](https://medium.com/@sdrzn/swifty-approach-to-handling-uitextviews-with-links-in-cells-d89e0e4b83d1#.fznxpite8).

You can learn more about the difference between `hitTest(_:with:)` and `point(inside:with:)` by reading Apple's [Guide and Sample Code: "Event Delivery: The Responder Chain"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW2).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It works great. I modified it slightly to handle  the case where layoutManager chooses the closest character to the point and a link is the last character. 

`let glyphIndex = layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: point, in: textContainer)
        let lineRect = layoutManager.lineFragmentUsedRect(forGlyphAt: glyphIndex, effectiveRange: nil)
        if point.x > lineRect.maxX {
            return nil
}`

Comment: This answer is good. Just the link tap area is small for the font size.

Comment: So I add more "link at point" detection around the tap point.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I solved it by subclassing UITextView and add a protocol :

```
@protocol SOTextViewDelegate;

@interface SOTextView : UITextView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SOTextViewDelegate> soDelegate;

@end

@protocol SOTextViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)soTextViewWasTapped:(SOTextView *)soTextview;

@end
```

In the implementation I've just added this :

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (self.selectedRange.length == 0 &&
        [_soDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(soTextViewWasTapped:)]))

        [_soDelegate soTextViewWasTapped:self];
}
```

This delegate will tell the custom cell that the textView was tapped. My custom cell also have a delegate in order to trigger its actual selection.

**Now you can tap on a link and it will open, you can tap on the textView and be notified and you still can select text and tap to deselect it.**