# UITextView inside UITableViewCell - touch go through if not clicking on a link

Tags: ios, uitableview, touch, uitextview, datadetectortypes

I'm trying to have the advantage of the UITextView with Data Detector Types inside a TableViewCell that is itself clickable.

The only thing is, I need the UITextView's links to be clickable, so userInteractionEnabled = YES, unfortunately this will prevent any touch going through to the UITableViewCell.

Of course the UITextView can't be edited, I also subclassed it refusing it to be first responder to avoid selecting text in it.

The only thing I need, is detecting that if a user touch the UITextView, check if it was a link, if it is then opening the link, otherwise redirect the touch on the UITableViewCell.

any idea how can this be done ?

much like the twitter App (we can either click on the row, or on the link...)

Comment: You can look at my fresh answer [right there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23309030/3441677)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [issue enabling dataDetectorTypes on a UITextView in a UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347727/issue-enabling-datadetectortypes-on-a-uitextview-in-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: @jrc my answer seems to be a more complete solution.

Comment: @jrc you are right, next time I found a better solution, I should just keep it to myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that this question has been asked a while ago, but the behaviour is still very much needed for some app to have a clickable Cell with UIDataDetectors.

So here's the UITextView subclass I made up to fit this particular behaviour in a UITableView

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *obj = self;

    do {
        obj = obj.superview;
    } while (![obj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]);
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)obj;

    do {
        obj = obj.superview;
    } while (![obj isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]);
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView*)obj;

    NSIndexPath *indePath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [[tableView delegate] tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indePath];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {
    return YES;
}
```

You can modify this to fit your needs...

Hope it helps someone.